# Unable to read from webservice in signed apk

Tags: android

After signing the apk the code is not reading from web service. I tried to debug and found that the BufferedReader is not reading any line. As per some answers in other stackoverflow questions I have turned off progaurd also but still no good. This is only happening in signed apk.

```
 public class LoanRatesWS extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<LoanRatesBn>> {

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    InputStream in;
    String line;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    int httpStatus;
    boolean isTimeout = false;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        String loadingMessage = resources.getString(R.string.loadingMessage);
        Utilities.startProgressDialog(progressDialog, loadingMessage);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<LoanRatesBn> doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(Utilities.getConnTimeout(MainActivity.this));
            connection.connect();
            httpStatus = connection.getResponseCode();
            in = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("Loans");

            ArrayList<LoanRatesBn> loanRatesBnArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                LoanRatesBn loanRatesBn = gson.fromJson(finalObject.toString(), LoanRatesBn.class);
                loanRatesBnArrayList.add(loanRatesBn);
            }
            return loanRatesBnArrayList;

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
            Utilities.stopProgressDialog(progressDialog);
            isTimeout = true;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Utilities.stopProgressDialog(progressDialog);

        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<LoanRatesBn> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (isTimeout) {
            Utilities.timeoutErrorAlert(MainActivity.this);
        } else if (Utilities.isValidResponse(httpStatus)) {
            Utilities.stopProgressDialog(progressDialog);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoanRates.class);
            Resources res = MainActivity.this.getResources();
            intent.putExtra("pageName", res.getString(R.string.loanRatesStr));
            intent.putExtra("loanRatesBnArrayList", result);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Utilities.serverErrorAlert(MainActivity.this);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an exception in Logcat? Or does the app just wait for a response from the webservice? You should debug your code to see if/where it hangs.

Comment: add some `Log.d` calls inside `doInBackground` to trace it somehow...

Comment: No the code hangs no where. Even the HTTP status is 200. But there are exceptions in the logcat but that is due to the subsequent objects remain null. Some thing wrong is happening in these lines: 2-9 of the doInBackground

Comment: so add `Log.d` calls to narrow it down